# Are there two types of scientific theories (one materialistic and one mathematical)?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, theory, categorization

Until recently, I was assured, for years, that there is only one way for a theory to be "scientific" (my definition):

> An hypothesis to solve a defined practical problem, which must be falsifiable;
> A scientific question should be asked (tested) to reinforce the falsifiable theory as plausible or implausible.

But,

Recently I have learned that this "[Popperian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Popper)" methodology isn't plausible in what I can define as `generally totally abstract sciences` such as Formal Logic, Mathematics and Computer science where the "falsifiable or unfalsifiable" paradigm doesn't catch because everything is "abstract" anyway.

Are there two types of scientific theories (one materialistic and one mathematical)?

Comment: Correct: mathematics and logic do not fit under Popperian's category of *falsifiable*.

Comment: See [The “science” of pseudoscience](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pseudo-science/#SciPse): "The English word “science” is primarily used about the natural sciences and other fields of research that are considered to be similar to them."

Comment: See also the post [Does Popper's theory of falsification apply to mathematics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/does-poppers-theory-of-falsification-apply-to-mathematics)

Comment: See K.R.Popper, [Conjectures and Refutations, page 67](https://books.google.it/books?id=zXh9AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA67) : "The Greeks' discovery of the critical method gave rise at first to the mistaken hope that it would
lead to the solution of all the great old problems; that it would establish certainty; that it would help to prove our theories, to justify them. But this hope was a residue of the dogmatic way of thinking; in fact nothing can be *justified* or *proved* (outside of mathematics and logic)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will confess up front that I am honestly confused why people still cling to Popper's work.
Even Popper himself eventually came to admit that his philosophy of science wasn't much more than an abstract aspiration, having little relation to the actual practice of science. Popper had some useful insights, sure, and an important place in the history of the philosophy of science, but seriously... Time to let that old dog rest.

Whinging aside, if we ask how many 'kinds' of science there are, we're going to get different answers depending on who we put the question to:

- Popper would say there's one thing called 'Science' that is done within certain limits, and nothing else applies.
- Kuhn would argue that every field creates a version of 'science' around its own central paradigm, and that even these paradigms can occasionally shift so that fields might have different understandings of 'science' at different points in their history.
- Feyerabend (whose name I always misspell, dang it) would argue that there is no 'science' in the general sense; there is only the singular behavior of individual scientists in their practice, with a wide multitude of 'sciences' that results from all their efforts.

### Popperian falsification as non rigorous

The common element of most philosophies of science is the observation that science is an ongoing *practice*: an activity/verb, not a thing/noun.
In this sense, when we try to think about whether something is 'scientific,' we don't mean whether it is/isn't within the class of objects labeled 'science.' Instead, we are asking whether the topic is approached in a manner that conforms to certain analytical/methodological constraints. This was part of the problem with Popper's falsificationism: the act of 'falsification' is not itself methodologically rigorous.
Just to take your example, let's say I wanted to 'scientifically' test math. Simple test: I decide to see whether 1+1=2 in some concrete context.

- I take one apple and I put it on a table
- I repeat that process;
- I count the apples on the table.
- If there are more or less than two apples on the table, then I've
  falsified addition!

Of course, there *are* two apples on the table (unless I got hungry), so addition survives the first effort at falsification. So I try again:

- I take one water and pour it into a bowl
- I repeat the process
- I look in the bowl and count the waters I have
- If there are more or less than two waters, then I've falsified addition!

Oh, err... Everyone will object that I've made a mistake by using 'waters' (which are not properly 'countable') and so addition has not *actually* been falsified. Popper would be forced to say, here, that this kind of manipulation — where mathematicians redefine the subject matter with new concepts (like 'countability') in order to preserve the core theory — means that mathematics is unfalsifiable, and thus not scientific. But as a *process* this is a perfectly normal scientific activity, where researchers redefine and recategorize observable data in order to make theories more exacting and coherent. So don't place quite so much credit on Popperean accounts of 'science.'

Comment: Whether it's Popper's precise formulation or not, there must be an aspect of testable predictions for a theory to be scientific.  It is not necessarily Popper-like "falsifiable" but it must be distinguishable from other theories, at least in principle.  Also, your examples don't test addition, they test the mapping of the operations onto addition.

Comment: I personally suggest to edit the chapter `Popperian falsification as non rigorous` which might be a bit long; should there be created a summarized version of it?

Comment: @puppetsock: Most scientific theories test mappings, not actual theories. e.g., most physics experiments measure rate-of-fall, which is assumed to map onto *gravitational attraction* (which is not directly observable). That's usually a non-issue, though it sometimes creates an opportunity for analysis by reexamining the mappings in question.

Comment: @puppetsock: And while I agree with the general empiricist view that there must be some observational measures in science, theories often precede measurement or measurability. Einstein had no conception how to measure many of the predictions of general relativity, but people took his theories as validly scientific regardless.

Comment: @JohnDoea: I usually try to scope sections so they fit on a decent sized computer screen without scrolling (which is a severe reduction from the normal academic metric, which is that a section should be as long as it needs to be to be complete, concise, and coherent). Do you really think two paragraphs and two bulleted lists is too long an exposition?

Comment: @TedWrigley  What do you mean Einstein had no conception how to measure predictions? His original paper on GR suggested the bending of sunlight during an eclipse as a test. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_May_29,_1919#Observations  And his original SR paper explained several existing measurement problems.

Comment: @puppetsock: But he had neither the means nor the methodology to test it; it was *speculative*. If I remember correctly, the bulk of the evidence for Einstein's theory has only arrived since his death, as technology improved sufficiently to make operationalization possible.

Comment: @TedWrigley Wow dude! You've re-invented the "no true Scottsman" fallacy. Well done.

Comment: @puppetsock: By pointing out that theories often precede evidence? Seems more like I've discovered your Ostrich Point (the place where you stick your head in the sand and pretend noting happened).

Comment: @TedWrigley I think it is often possible: By amount of content per character I just feel it might be too long and a summary of some sort is worth weighing; BTW it's not merely for me but first of all for the community and future readers...

Comment: @JohnDoea: Let me think on it for a day...

Comment: The word is whining. How did this awful "whinging" thing get started? There is no such word.

Comment: @user4894: "whinge | (h)winj | British : verb [no object] to complain persistently and in a peevish or irritating way."

Comment: @TedWrigley Today I learned! Thanks. Did not realize that's an actual word. Not an American word though.

Comment: @TedWrigley It is the nature of proposed experimental verifications of theories that their outcomes are speculative; if they are not, than what you have, instead, is an explanation for an already-known phenomenon (which is also valuable.) On the other hand, there was -- and is -- nothing speculative about what general relativity predicts, so Eddington's observations were a significant event. Because, per Bohr, predicing the future is particularly difficult, success at it is particularly significant.

Comment: @sdenham: Sure, but that just reinforces the point that the 'science' part of this is in the process of working with the theory, not in the theory itself.

Comment: Fortunately, science will still get done, even if the philosophy is not complete and universally agreed upon.